# Attaching to a screen session on boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, cron, crontab

What I'm trying to do is start a screen session on boot via crontab and then have the user automatically connect to that session.

Here's my current cron file:

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command

@reboot screen -dmS RunScript sh /root/start.sh
```

Here the screen session is created, however I can't seem to get connected to it without having to run the connect to session command manually.

I can run

```
screen -dmS RunScript sh /root/start.sh && screen -r RunScript
```

in order to start the session and connect to it, however, it doesn't apply in crontab as I assume it's a separate process.

Is there a I can achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do what I was trying to do by having the service run the start script on boot and then connecting to the screen session via the .bash_login file